# DirectX background image

Tags: c++, directx

I tried to follow a tutorial from my 3D directx book with some modifications. The problem I encountered is that I want to draw an image but can't get this working. The example is working with a camera since it's based on a small game but I just want to load the image without any fancy camera transformations. (Draw the image as it is without resizing + alpha blending).

This is my code which should contain the relevant parts.

.h

```
class Screen
{
private:
    IDirect3DTexture9* m_BGImage;
    ID3DXSprite* m_Sprite;

    IDirect3DDevice9* m_Device;

public:
    Screen();
    ~Screen();

    void setDevice(IDirect3DDevice9* device);  
    void setBGImage(std::string path);

    void Draw();
    void onLostDevice();
    void onResetDevice();

    void Clean();
};
```

.cpp

```
Screen::Screen() {}

Screen::~Screen()
{
    Clean();
}

void Screen::setDevice(IDirect3DDevice9* device) 
{
    m_Device = device;
    D3DXCreateSprite(m_Device, &m_Sprite);
}

void Screen::setBGImage(std::string path)
{
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(m_Device, path.c_str(), &m_BGImage);
}

void Screen::Draw()
{
    m_Sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_DONOTMODIFY_RENDERSTATE); // This is (so I believe) what causes the problem. If I use D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE|D3DXSPRITE_DONOTMODIFY_RENDERSTATE like described in the example from my book I only get a black screen.

    m_Sprite->Draw(m_BGImage, 0, &D3DXVECTOR3(256.0f, 256.0f, 0.0f), 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
    m_Sprite->Flush();

    m_Sprite->End();
}

void Screen::Clean()
{
    ReleaseCOM(m_Sprite);
    ReleaseCOM(m_BGImage);
}

void Screen::onLostDevice()
{
    m_Sprite->OnLostDevice();
}

void Screen::onResetDevice()
{
    m_Sprite->OnResetDevice();

    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, 10);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC, D3DCMP_GREATER);

    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);

    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_COUNT2);
}
```

Edit: Almost forgot:

```
#define ReleaseCOM(x) { if(x){ x->Release(); x = 0; } }
```

Comment: Not very familiar with DX, so apologies if this is off the mark, but one thing that might be worth looking into:  if you're not doing any object-to-view transforms, then the object is being defined relative to view space.. which means you'll often need to define it with a Z offset so that it's actually inside the view frustrum, otherwise it'll just get culled.  For example, a half-unit cube centered at the origin of view space won't render if your near clip plane is at z=1.

Comment: Well since I'm not even close to a pc with a compiler for the next view days I can't test it but I will as soon as I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

You should use D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND instead of D3DXSPRITE_DONOTMODIFY_RENDERSTATE when calling function "Begin", specify D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND does not mean you must use alpha blend, if you don't call Screen::onResetDevice(), the alpha blend won't work, so D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND here is just a parameter to make "Begin" works. if you don't want to specify any flags when calling function "Begin", you can pass 0 to it.

```
 m_Sprite->Begin(0); 
 m_Sprite->Draw(m_BGImage, 0, &D3DXVECTOR3(256.0f, 256.0f, 0.0f), 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
 m_Sprite->Flush();
 m_Sprite->End();
```

reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205466(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)